# Survey Questions Score Object Records are not available to query

Tags: survey

I am trying to query Survey Questions Score Object Records but I am not able to query via user. User doesn't have the View All Data permission on to the profile. Actually I do not wants to give this permission to the user as this permission will be applicable for all the objects. But I can also not see the Survey Questions Score Object on UI to give the permission separately for the profile. Can anyone please help me how to give View all access to Survey Questions Score Object on to the profile so that I can query the records only for this object.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you tried to give view access to the "Survey" and "Survey Responses" object? The Survey Questions Score object represents the aggregate of responses, so I don't think it is related to the "Survey Response" object. Those two I mentioned before can have the access specified.

Comment: @Renato Oliveira Yes I have tried to give View all perm to "Survey" & "Survey Responses" but still I am not able to query any record for the user.